# How to filter an array which has different elements?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a TableView, from which I am getting the selected `tableViewCell's` values in an array but it's not the desired array:

> `[<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016\> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}: "test1234", 
>   <NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}: "Judson"]`

How can I filter it to get `["test1234","Judson"]`?

This is the code I am using:

```
var selectedTextLabels = [NSIndexPath: String]()

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! UsersTableViewCell
    if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None;
        selectedTextLabels[indexPath] = nil
    } else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark;
        if (cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark){
            if let text = cell.collegeNameLbl?.text {
                selectedTextLabels[indexPath] = text
            }
        }
    }
    print("\(selectedTextLabels)  outside")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `var selectedTextLabels = [NSIndexPath: String]()` is a dictionary and you are trying to retrieve the `String` part of it, namely the `values` you can get them via:

```
let values = Array(selectedTextLabels.values)
```